# Opentelemetry: Open span in one process, and close it in another

Tags: go, trace, open-telemetry, nats.io

I'm looking into using OpenTelementry golang library to record a function which is connected together by distributed messaging (NATS). I want to start a span, post a message to the second part of the function, and end the span when that completes.

I can only see examples of spans that close when a function ends.

It would be great if I could create a span and pass in an existing id to use, and get a recording span back, but it doesn't look like this is possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not possible. Only TraceID shared between services. Please clarify why do you need it. Two independent but connected spans works pretty good for me.

Comment: I've written a distributed workflow engine that:

Listener receives start message and starts execution of a workflow step.

Pushes a state execute message to a message queue.

Task listener executes user code.

Pushes a state complete message to the message queue.

Listener receives a complete message and completes workflow step.

Pushes traversal message to the message queue.

The problem I have is that I want to trace workflow steps, but the execution is distributed. 
Edited to include some context:
https://gitlab.com/shar-workflow/shar

Comment: You can create a span if one not already initialized. See https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/go/manual/#creating-spans

Answer (score 1):

> Open span in one process, and close it in another

That is not a very good idea. With a single span, you can see total process execution time, but cannot see time and details of its parts.

It is more helpful if you can create a span for every important step. It could be a local function or function executed in an external process.

I found that nice slide in internet that demonstrates what we can achive.

https://speakerdeck.com/simonz130/distributed-tracing-and-monitoring-with-opentelemetry?slide=26

[image]

As @pati-ram-yadav mentioned in comment, you can create child spans using `span := trace.SpanFromContext(ctx)` inside application.

For external process it is a bit more complicated.

Parent function needs to share context (accountID and traceID) with child function through the wire.

After that, the child process injects these fields into its context and all spans created with that context are connected to the parent.

Every transport implements sending additional data (accountID and traceID) differently. With HTTP, for example, it is implemented as custom HTTP headers.

Many transports including HTTP are supported by opentelemetry out-of-the-box. If some transport is not supported, you have to find a community module or write your own code.

This is an example for HTTP. You need to [Inject](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/blob/d1faf5c6c7ed4aac0961182bad1088645095a9c1/instrumentation/net/http/httptrace/otelhttptrace/httptrace.go#L77) context into HTTP request in parent and [Extract](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/blob/d1faf5c6c7ed4aac0961182bad1088645095a9c1/instrumentation/net/http/httptrace/otelhttptrace/httptrace.go#L63) that context from the request in client. Client then adds TraceID and AccountID to `context.Context` and all spans created using that context are connected to parent span.

Comment: An important lesson for distributed systems is that any system that uses a 'fire and forget' strategy for dispatching tasks to other systems is a system where work can simply disappear and nobody notices it.  This is considered one of the classic blunders. A system that is monitoring the tasks can also manage the telemetry lifecycle. A system with no monitoring has to pass all of the monitoring responsibility around, which is brittle. If nobody is responsible, then everyone is responsible, and therefore anyone can/will break it.